# about sharepoint login

Tags: sharepoint-2007

When i open the sharepoint site,the login dialog box appears on the screen.How can i ensure that when the user wants to login,he clicks the sign in(button) at the top of the page and login into the website?
And if user clicks cancel on login dialog box then the page is redirected to a page which showing an error message as 401 unauthorized.I want the page to redirect to home page when the user clicks cancel button.what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to enable anonymous access to your site. If the user wants to sign in he can sign in by clicking the sign in link at the top (which will appear when you enable anonymous access to the site).

To enable anonymous access

1. Central Administration ->
   Application Management ->
   Authentication Providers
2. Select you web application and zone
3. Check 'Enable Anonymous Access'
4. Save it
5. Go to the web application
6. People & Groups -> Site permissions -> Settings -> Anonymous Access
7. Select 'Entire Web Site'
8. Save it